# RewriteRule [P] in .htaccess covers only the root level of files - need all levels

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using

```
RewriteRule "^special_folder/(.*)$"  "http://my_new_domain.com/$1"  [P]
```

With this it will reference/use (but keep hidden) **my_new_domain.com** when I am in **my_old_domain.com/special_folder/** and that is all well and good.

However, when i click on a link to a deeper folder in wordpress, it loses the mask and shows **my_new_domain.com/deeper_folder** which i dont want it to do. I want it to keep the mask and display **my_old_domain.com/special_folder/even_more_special_folder**

Perhaps I can modify this existing line to cover all subdirectories.  Any better ideas or suggestions?

Additionally, I need the links on my site to not point towards **my_new_domain.com** ever, but to of course continue to point towards **my_old_domain.com/special_folder/** ... is that possible?

Comment: can I bump this?  been two days without a response...